# cassandra node discovery

Tags: cassandra

I just set up a 3 node system with ip addresses "192.168.0.101", "192.168.0.102", "192.168.0.103". I have set the seeds value on the configuration of all three machines as 
`seeds: "192.168.0.101,192.168.0.102,192.168.0.103"`

However, on running nodetool on any of them, only the `103` machine gets discovered.

> node101:/opt/cassandra/apache-cassandra-0.8.5/bin# ./nodetool
>   ring -h 192.168.0.101 Address         DC          Rack        Status
>   State   Load            Owns    Token
>
> 192.168.0.103   datacenter1 rack1       Up     Normal  151.96 KB
>   100.00% 38174485210079977599903748344879358256

Could someone tell me where the problem lies?

Comment: you should never put all your nodes as seeds. just saying.

Answer (score 8):

Seeds are really only important when bootstrapping new machines into a cluster, and they should only be set to mature members of the cluster.

In a three-node cluster, I usually:

1. Fully bring up the first node. Thrift and nodetool should both work with it.
2. Install Cassandra on the second and third nodes.
3. Stop Cassandra on the second and third nodes and wipe the data (if you're on a Debian-style distro where installing a package starts the service)
4. Configure the second and third nodes to use the first as a seed.
5. Configure the listen addresses one all three nodes to be IPs that the other nodes can reach.
6. Start the second node.
7. Start the third node.
8. Watch /var/log/cassandra/system.log on each node for notifications about others joining the ring.

In your case (not seeing discovery), I would double-check the following:

- That the listen address on each node is ping-able from each other
  node.
- That the cluster name is the same on all three nodes.
- That no node complains about the cluster name on disk not matching the
  configured one.
- That nodes mention in system.log that they're hearing
  about other nodes coming online.

Also, please run the nodetool ring command on each node and see if they all think they're members of single-node rings.

Comment: I agree that on creation you should have only one seed and usual follow something similar to your steps. However, once the system is up and running, having more than one seed is probably important., unless you are just playing with a test cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you setup the listen address to the ip's.  By default Cassandra does a reverse DNS on the hostname, which can result in binding localhost depending on how your machines are setup.